# Python - missing zeep and binascii

Tags: python, conda, zeep, binascii

I am trying to run the following yml file. When it runs I get the error below.  I use command

```
conda env create -f myTool.yml
```

myTool.yml

```
name: myTool
dependencies:
- python=3.7
- xlrd
- openpyxl
- re2
- zeep
- pandas
- binascii
- requests
```

The Error I get:

> (base) C:\Users\myProfile\pythonYML>conda env create -f myTool.yml
> Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done Solving environment:
> failed
>
> ResolvePackageNotFound:
>
> - zeep
> - binascii

If I type "Python" in the terminal I get this...

> (base) C:\Users\myProfile\pythonYML>python Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan
> 8 2020, 20:23:39) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on
> win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more
> information.
>
> > > > 

My python install came with anaconda. I did opt to add the PATH variable.  Any and all suggestions appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `zeep` and `binascii` are available as Conda packages? Are you using the correct channel(s) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install zeep

pip install pycopy-binascii
```

You need to install these libraries (execute both commands in terminal separately ) in the same environment that you are using and also need to make sure that you're using python 3.7 or higher .

After doing this , try running you .yml file again!